# My app exits randomly after some time period on android and ios Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using unity version 2022.3.15f1 .
On editior it works fine I am having the issue on android and ios build.
I created an app download json data from webrequest and display it on the screen. It get display duration and refresh rate from the json if the refresh rate is 1 it will download the data every second and change the display accordingly .
First version was it displays the text data with flipflap animation it was working fine.
Now i created the second version with pictures it will get the picture url from json, download(Not saving it locally ) and split the picture into row columns and display on flipflap animation.
But now it randomly exit after some random time 5mins to 2hours its completely random time.
Even with  the text version (1) the app randomly exits now.
Is there any way to debug what's causing it?

if (Data.currentPage.pictures != null && Data.currentPage.type == 2)       //Pictures
{
print(Data.currentPage.pictures);

```
 if (Data.currentPage.pictures != previousPicture)
 {
     DataUpdated = true;
     new WebRequest(this, Data.currentPage.pictures, (sprite) =>
     {
         Texture2D image = sprite.texture;

         imageTiles.Clear();
         Split(image, Data.currentPage.rows, Data.currentPage.columns);
         SetBoard(Data.currentPage.rows, Data.currentPage.columns, true);



         StartCoroutine(ChangePicturesOverTime(Data.currentPage.Duration, Data.currentPage.rows, Data.currentPage.columns));

     },
     (errpr, type) =>
     {
         print("PIC FAIL");
         GameManager.instance.startTime = false;
         GameManager.instance.duration = 0;
         GetData.instance.Wait10StartDownloadData();
     });
 }
 else
 {
     DataUpdated = false;
     SetBoard(Data.currentPage.rows, Data.currentPage.columns, true);

     if (previousPageIndex != Data.currentPageIndex )
     {
         DataUpdated = true;
     }

     StartCoroutine(ChangePicturesOverTime(Data.currentPage.Duration, Data.currentPage.rows, Data.currentPage.columns));
 }
```

}
else //Text
{
StartCoroutine(ChangeAlphabetsOverTime(2, previousRows, previousCols, charachters));
}

I tried using logcat to debug whats causing it but it does not show any crash log or error it just exits .